# Using WPF/MVVM, how do I immediately restore focus to my application after closing extnernal process?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a full screen WPF application that launches external processes when the user selects an item from a listbox. Navigation with the listbox is done primarily with the keyboard and not the mouse. What is the cleanest way to immediately return focus to the listbox once the user closes the external app? I've got it working, but the solution is not ideal as far as I'm concerned and is a bit "hacky".

Here's the XAML:

```
<ListBox SelectedIndex="{Binding ActiveSelection, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                 IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" x:Name="ListBoxSelector">
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

And the code:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var process = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe");
    process.WaitOnExit()
    ActiveSelection += 1;
    ActiveSelection -= 1;
}
```

So basically changing the ActiveSelection (and then back again so the same thing is still selected) seems to focus the listbox instantly once the MSPaint program closes. So I've achieved the desired outcome, but I think there's probably a better and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Focus is a view concern.

So a *direct* approach would be to have whatever model/service your `Process.Start` is raise an event when the process exits, have the VM pick that up and raise an event in turn, and finally have the view react by setting the focus.

Alternatively, the VM could set a property say `CurrentlyInExternalApplication` that when set to false by the aforementioned event would cause a trigger (similar to your existing one) to fire.

Comment: Is this the same approach that @opewix demonstrated with the code sample? Is the "raise an event" part referring to process.WaitForExit() portion of the code?

Comment: No, he's not really using a MVVM approach there @alduin

Comment: So how would I go about raising an event with the process exits if not using WaitForExit()? Currently I have the Process.Start code in my view model, should it not be there? Sorry for my lack of knowledge, I'm still familiarizing myself with all of the WPF syntax and trying to learn MVVM properly.

Comment: @alduin The `Process.Start` should be in your model (likely as a service class). That class *could* use `WaitForExit` (careful about blocking the calling thread though!) or look for the `Exited` event (also on `Process`). Note that `TaskCompletionSource` could be your friend in several ways here

Comment: I was able to "hack" in a solution that gets the desired result but it doesn't adhere to anything you were talking about. I couldn't really figure out where to go with that as my knowledge on WPF/MVVM is still pretty basic. So I would welcome some more guidance on getting a cleaner solution.

Comment: Please ask a new question about it, or consider joining us in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18165/wpf chat

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run child process in a new thread and call `process.WaitForExit()` after it is started. Then, after child process is closed you can make your app focus using `Dispatcher` since the current thread is not a UI thread.

```
var process = Process.Start(@"C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe");
process.WaitForExit();
Dispatcher.Invoke(() => MainWindow.Current.MakeFocus()); // sample line
```

Your MainWindow should have a static property `Current` and it should be set when your main app is started.

Comment: Does Current get set in the MainWindow.xaml.cs file? I was under the impression that it was bad practice with MVVM to have code in there. And is Current supposed to be a specific variable type? Sorry, still quite new to WPF/MVVM.

Comment: Yes `Current` is a static variable in MainWindow.xaml.cs. `public static MainWindow Current {get; private set;}`. You can set it in `MainWindow` constuctor. `MakeFocus()` is your custom method that is responsible for setting focus

Comment: This is not really MVVM. The model shouldn't do *anything* directly to a view

Comment: @BradleyDotNET I'm not telling this is MVVM, it's just a technical approach of waiting for process exit